# What might it be the best collaborative tool for short term project?

Tags: svn, version-control

I, we, find ourselves collaborating for a short time (to be defined: but it can be 1 week, 1 month, 1 year) with some external entities. I call it entities because it can be a single person but also a huge multi-multi company.

The problem is that all the communications have been, so far, always done for the client side, which also meant a lot of work. It would be easier if we can present a collaboration tool: SVN, TortoiseSVN, or something else.

The solution should be OS independent, and a working deliverable.
I personally kinda stick to some SVN tool, but I might need
some heavy personalization.

So the question: What do you use as a collaboration tool? Which one is the best (if any)?
Assuming an heterogeneous environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'll support previous posters in light of using Mercurial (but remember - own Subversion /over Apache/ is more manageable, from my POV)...

but have to mention - collaboration in full sense is not only code (thus - SCM of choice), it's more - communications, coordinated actions (outside the "pure coding"): if you mission is "Things must be done", just *VCS is insufficiently.

PS - for my **any-time** projects I prefer to use [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/), new repo in existing space or totally new space with *needed-for-project toolset*

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "collaboration" tool you mean source code management/revision control, since you are bringing up SVN as an example.

It would appear that the days of centralized revision control systems such as CVS and SVN are numbered, and the overhead of running them seems especially unjustified for a small group or short term project.

Personally and professionally I have migrated with great success to [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com).  It's written in Python (and thus cross-platform) and has a user experience that is much superior (IMHO) to [Git](http://git-scm.com/), its chief "competitor."

It's fairly easy to setup one server to act as an "authoritative" repository if you would like to mimic how CVS and SVN work.  You can also work in a completely distributed manner, with changesets pushed between clients.

To give it a try, install on your platform and try:

```
hg init MyTestRepo
cd MyTestRepo
touch SampleFile.c
hg add SampleFile.c
hg commit
hg log
```

That should give you an idea of the workflow and how much you like it.  Tutorials abound on the Internet to help you move on with use in an actual project.

Answer (score 0):

Any version control system will provide you with a "collaboration tool". That is the main role of a version control system: to provide a structured way for developers to work together.

I prefer [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) myself since it's light-weight, fast, and distributed. There are (graphical) clients for all platforms: [TortoiseHg](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) (Windows, Linux, Mac), [MacHg](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/) and [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (Mac).